# How to return null/false/override such filter in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, filter

This is an example i want to `null/false/override`

Example Code:

```
add_filter('modify_js_string', [$this, 'exclude_modify_js_string']);
```

Comment: Essentially it's this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950435/remove-action-defined-within-plugin-class/64446658#64446658 but `remove_filter` instead of action

Comment: i see, but it's not working for filter, filter should be different approach i see.