# Wordpress - remove_action from plugin class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WordPress, how can I remove the action below, which is inside a class in a plugin?

The plugin includes this (I'm just quoting a few lines of it):

```
class WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Admin {
    public static function init() {
        self::$self = new self();
        add_action( 'pre_get_users', array( self::$self, 'filter_users' ) );
    }
}
WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Admin::init();
```

In my own custom plugin, I tried:

```
function remove_my_class_action() {
    remove_action ( 'pre_get_users', array( WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Admin::$instance , 'filter_users') );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_my_class_action' );
```

But Wordpress doesn't even let me save it — it says the class is not found.

I also tried `getInstance()` instead of `$instance`.

Instead of `'plugins_loaded'` I also tried `'wp_head'` and `'init'`.

Also tried different priorities on both add_action and remove_action, it doesn't make a difference. (Though it could be there's some combination of the above that I missed.)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950435/remove-action-defined-within-plugin-class/64446658#64446658

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried instantiating the class as the answer there suggests and it still tells me `Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Admin' not found in wp-content/plugins/mycustomplugin/custom-roles.php:107`

Comment: You could check if `class_exisits` ... I would assume that the vendor admin class is an admin function?

Comment: On its own `class_exists` returns false ... if I put `remove_action` in a conditional with `if (class_exists(...)`, I can at least save the file, but then the site shows an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Admin::$instance in ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the same hook with higher priority (default is 10). Also the static property `$instance` doesn't exist on that class.
In the code you paste from the plugin you can see that in the init function it uses the `$self` static property to store the instance.

```
function remove_my_class_action() {
    remove_action ( 'pre_get_users', array( WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Admin::$self , 'filter_users') );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'remove_my_class_action', 9 );
```

Comment: This did the job. Thank you!